# React Native - Expo Stuck on "Downloading Javascript Bundle 100%"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

For months I've been working on this project and never once came across this issue.
Suddenly expo does not go beyond the splash screen, I've searched multiple forums and none of the suggested solutions worked.

I've tried:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling expo (both mobile and PC)
2. Clearing expo data on mobile
3. Stopping remote debugging
4. Clearing yarn cache
5. Undoing last known changes.
6. Updating my Expo CLI
7. I commented everything and prevented navigation away from the startup page, then tried printing only a text output in a View.
8. I built a new blank expo project which works, but I'd rather not transfer all of my code to a new project, it doesn't seem like a logical fix since the new project would just become the old once everything is moved.

**There are no errors** in the code, I can deliberately cause a syntax error and it'll display as usual with the error screen on mobile and in the terminal log, once the error is fixed it goes back to not passing the splash screen again.

**Update:**
I've commented every line in the project and removed comments one by one to see when the problem occurs. Here is what I've found, it occurs:

1. When I include `import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";` but it doesn't cause the same issue when the same import is used in another route.
2. When I include `Stylesheet.create({...})` even though Stylesheet works in other routes.
3. When I include `import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';` and this works fine when used in other routes also.

There doesn't seem to be a pattern.

Comment: are you trying with emulator? did you try hard reseting the emulator (wiping out all data)?

Comment: Hey, no I'm using a mobile

Comment: Did you try deleting both `node_modules` and `.expo` folders and then `npm install` and then `npm start`?

Comment: I tried deleting node_modules, I'll try removing .expo as well now

Comment: Sennen are you sure that the .expo folder returns with npm install (in my case yarn) ? I've deleted it but now I can't get it back

Comment: @NathanWright No, `.expo` folder is created when you run `npm start` or `expo start`.

Comment: ok Sennen, I tried it, that didn't work

Comment: Try `expo start -c`

Comment: @GM-atteoni that doesn't work